# Amazon S3 file metadata headers not showing in ajax response

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using angular to send a HEAD request to a file in an S3 bucket. With Postman, the headers come back as the following:

```
Accept-Ranges → bytes
Content-Length → 59957693
Content-Type → application/pdf
Date → Sun, 27 Dec 2015 20:23:51 GMT
ETag → "b6971aa1f1d0787aa0857574259086a1"
Last-Modified → Wed, 05 Nov 2014 02:59:45 GMT
Server → AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2 → 4YNymxHqBhCOiLGltqvOj+vDySUCoa7PjVN340S9U1AyvFfqGVcBgegDygKkzx0YruzpCfvmC4s=
x-amz-request-id → CC64C650A759B048
```

For some reason when using an angular request, the status comes back as 200, but the headers does not return the entire object.

```
Object {last-modified: "Wed, 05 Nov 2014 02:59:45 GMT", content-type: "application/pdf"}
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
$http.head($rootScope.issue.pdf_url).then(function(data, status, headers){
                   console.log(data, status, headers);
               })
```

I've done the following in AWS to allow CORS:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>5000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Is there something else that I need to configure in order to get access to the headers in the ajax response?